# How to search full-text mysql field in order to return only a sentence when the keyword is found (not to return the whole field)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, search, full-text-search

I have a fulltext field with some text.

Then I search a keyword using: `TABLENAME.FULLTEXT_FIELD REGEXP '[[:<:]]keyword'`

This returns the records where the keyword is in the `fulltext_field`.

What I'm trying to achieve is to return some text that surrounds my keyword (like Google search, at the homepage it gives you a sentence so you can get the context of your keyword).

Can this be done?

I think solving it in DB level would be better, though if this is difficult to be done in SQL can somebody help doing the same in PHP i.e getting the whole text and extracting only a sentence in php for my webpage.

Thanks.

Comment: Usually emboldening(bold letters) is performed. MySQL returns with most relevant records on top, use PHP to embolden keywords in returned records.

Comment: the thing is I want to cut only one sentence from the text. I'm reading on the web, one suggestion was to explode (.) the text using php and then do a sentence by sentence search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always return the records which include your text.

Then use **strpos** to determine the position of the start of your text. Then paste x-amount of characters before it and after it.